# Windows 10 taskbar drag and drop to reorder stopped working

Tags: windows, windows-10

Windows 10 taskbar drag and drop no longer works and drag and dropping to reorder the Chrome tabs does not work anymore either.

I am not aware of what could have caused this. I would prefer to not have to reset the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I did a system restore and that fixed the issue.